# Float to right, left and top grid

Tags: css, flexbox, vertical-alignment

I have that HTML:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="cell left">A</div>
  <div class="cell left">B</div>
  <div class="cell right">C</div>
  <div class="cell left">D</div>
  <div class="cell right">E</div>
  <div class="cell left">F</div>
</div>
```

I want to obtain that:

[Example:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wINpp.png)

All "cell left" have to be align to left and top.
All "cell right" have to be align to right and top.

The layout of the HTML must remain as is. How to define CSS using FLEX or FLOAT? The order or number of cells in each row is not known or regular.

I tried to do it using FLEX or FLOAT, but the right cells are not top-aligned.

Comment: Are you constrained to use flex or float as your question implies, because grid is often a better solution for 2D layouts such as you have here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution would be using `display: grid`.

[More about grid layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout)

When in `display: grid`, the placing of items can be specified such as:

```
/* In 2 columns of same size, auto place item by row and fill gaps */

grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
grid-auto-flow: row dense;
```

Then, `left` and `right` classes can specify which `grid-column` the `div` should be placed.

Here is a quick example:

```css
.row {
  display: grid;
  width: 500px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-auto-flow: row dense;
  gap: 12px;
  outline: 2px solid #000;
  padding: 12px;
}

.cell {
  padding: 12px;
}

.left {
  grid-column: 1 / span 1;
  background-color: pink;
}

.right {
  grid-column: 2 / span 1;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="cell left">A</div>
  <div class="cell left">B</div>
  <div class="cell right">C</div>
  <div class="cell left">D</div>
  <div class="cell right">E</div>
  <div class="cell left">F</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this solution.
Basically we're creating a flex container that flexes in a column direction so all elements go below each other. Then we increase width so that we have enough room for cells to be on left and cells to be on right. Finally in a flex container you can align elements to start, center, or end vertically or horizontally. And since we have 2 different classes with 2 different alignments, instead of doing a single align-items on the parent element (row) I did 2 self-align on each class, one on flex-start and other on flex-end.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <style>
    .row {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      width: 200px;
    }
    .left {
      align-self: flex-start;
    }
    
    .right {
      align-self: flex-end;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="row">
  <div class="cell left">A</div>
  <div class="cell left">B</div>
  <div class="cell right">C</div>
  <div class="cell left">D</div>
  <div class="cell right">E</div>
  <div class="cell left">F</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's not about that. Notice that there are spaces between B and D and D and F on the left and between C and E on the right. Also, C is not aligned to the top. See the "Example" image in my post.

Comment: I don't know if it's possible to do that without changing the actual HTML. I think putting position absolute on the right elements can stick them to top. However I'm not sure how you would create space between them since they're absolutely positioned. I tried nth-of-type property and top increments but it just moved all right elements.